# iOS Autoresizing Cell Labels Sometimes Clipped

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uikit, uilabel

I am writing an app (targeting iOS 10+, building with the iOS 10.3 SDK in Xcode 8.3.3) which displays a simple table view to the user. This table view is composed of a bunch of cells representing user-defined objects which have an optional title and mandatory (short) content. To display these, I am using `UILabel`, naturally.

I am also trying to use autoresizing cells. The view controller in which all the magic occurs is a subclass of `UITableViewController` (with a grouped table view), and in its `loadView` method, I configure it to use automatic resizing with

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 21
```

I then configure the cells with the following constraints (using symbolic shorthand):

- `nameLabel.topMargin = contentView.topMargin`
- `nameLabel.leftMargin = contentView.leftMargin`
- `nameLabel.rightMargin = contentView.rightMargin`
- `contentLabel.leftMargin = contentView.leftMargin`
- `contentLabel.rightMargin = contentView.rightMargin`
- `contentLabel.topMargin = nameLabel.bottomMargin`
- `contentView.bottomMargin = contentLabel.bottomMargin`

The labels are given `lineBreakMode`s of `.byWordWrapping` and `numberOfLines` is set to `0`. `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is, of course, set to `false`. They are assigned fonts using `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:)`.

This all works well — until the content label's exceeds the width of the cell by just a little bit. The cells resize properly if it wraps a little bit past the end of the cell, and then this content is hidden. It displays correctly, regardless of number of lines, once a certain wraparound length is reached, however. Here's a screenshot. Here, the content for the "Length" item is "This is a super duper long snippet, because we need to see how labels behave when they (more than barely) extend onto multiple lines." The content for the "Power Cycle" item is "Have you tried turning it off and back on again?" Strange, right? [image: Screenshot]
Adding a mere "Please advise." to the end of the "Length" item results in it rendering as expected, as shown below (and it's even a nice animated change).[image: Longer Screenshot]

The content label has a low content hugging priority and the name label has a high one. The content label has a high content compression resistance priority and the name label has a low one.

It may also be worth noting (more explicitly) that *this issue persists when I manually calculate cell heights using relevant APIs for sizes of strings and assign these heights explicitly in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`*.

I've been tearing my hair out over this issue for days now. I've written many, many fixes, including some strange ones and even some that use CoreText and friends. Nothing's worked properly. The old fixes for iOS 6 and company don't work. Something's up here, and I can't find it.

Thanks in advance for the help!

---

Before you refer me to other questions, please know that I have spent hours and hours scouring the Internet (Stack Overflow and elsewhere) for solutions to this problem, and all the solutions available do not work for my situation. Posting a smug, snarky response with a link to another question or blog post probably isn't going to help, and is just annoying. Relatedly, please don't tell me to just use a default cell style.

Comment: I can't check it myself at the moment, but try changing to `.byTruncatingTail` or `.byClipping` ... I *think* one of those works better than word-wrapping.

Comment: @DonMag As expected, `.byTruncatingTail` just displays ellipses if the word was clipped, which, while better than the current behavior of just not displaying any indication of the removal, isn't quite the behavior I want. `.byClipping` is similar to the existing behavior, but displays partial words when editing mode is entered. Thanks for the ideas, though!

Comment: Well, if you're looking for "things to try" to help resolve this... I'm curious - if you set a specific font as opposed to `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:)`, do you see any difference?

Comment: I just used the exact configuration that you have used, and I am not getting any issue with truncation.
I think the information that you provided is not the issue here. You must have added some other attributes to table view or label, that might be interfering here.

Comment: @DonMag I did try with other fonts, and the issue remains (assuming the correct size for the overflow conditions).

Comment: @HeadOnn The only things I didn't list are that I set `label.layoutMargins = .zero` for both labels and that the header/footer view heights are set to 18 (apparently the default in IB).

Comment: Just to clarify... Are you seeing this when the table is initially populated and displayed? Or only when you dynamically edit / add rows (I'm basing that on the `+` button)?

Comment: @DonMag Both initial render and upon editing.

Comment: Is this a `UITableViewController` in a NavController? Or is it a table view in a `UIViewController` in a NavController? Or either of those but *not* in a NavController (i.e. normal view with a navigation bar as a subview)? Is the tableview Plain or Grouped?

Comment: Table view is grouped, in a `UITableViewController` subclass within a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Hmm... seems like there must be something else going on. Maybe re-create your custom cell? I just ran a quick test https://imgur.com/a/YDUl0 ... you'll see that row 2 doesn't wrap, but I change the word "to" to "too" on the third row to force just enough for wrapping - and it auto-sizes fine.

Comment: By the way... I left all hugging and compression values at their defaults. If you want to compare, I put my sample project up at https://github.com/DonMag/SWSimpleDynamicCells

Comment: @DonMag I figured it out. Was overriding `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` a long time ago and never removed it, then missed it every time I looked. (D'oh!) Thanks for being so helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the weirdness I was seeing was the result of one of the harebrained "solutions" I had tried previously. In all my reviews of my code, my eyes glossed right over it, and so it never got removed.

In the table's delegate's `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, I was doing the following Bad Thing before returning:

```
if let c = cell as? MyAwesomeCellSubclass {
    c.contentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = tableView.bounds.size.width
    c.nameLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = tableView.bounds.size.width
}
```

You'd think I'd know better. Thanks to those who tried to help me in my stupidity!